# Access site behind login.microsoftonline oatuth2 with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm learning webscraping and I need to access a website which is behind login.microsoftonline.com with python but I can't find how to go through it.

How should I go through it ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.